# getParameternames() of servlet

Tags: servlets

In servlets - getParameterNames() returns the name passed in the request. 
I want to ask that if we have 3 form tags into one html file and we want to get the names from form1 and form3 then how we can pass the reference of the form with getParameterNames.

```
 Enumeration enum = req.getParameterNames();
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You will only get the parameters for the form that is submitted.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you could have hidden form inputs that contain the values of the non-submitted forms.  You can set those hidden values using javascript.

Comment: <html>
<form method="get" name="form1">
<input name="q" type="text">
<input value="Go!" type="Submit"> <br>
</form>
 
<form method="get" name="form2">

<input name="p" type="text">
<input value="Go!" type="submit">
</form>                 <html>                                                            If now i want to get the ParameterNames of form1 and form2 from a same servlet file then how to pass the reference.